# Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know why my website navbar in mobile won't close and open like I want. When the user clicks on those 3 bars, it should close and open in mobile view, but it just won't work. Here is the code for the navbar:

Here is my website. Just resize it, and you will see that it just stays there and won't close like I want it to.

Here is the website:
http://edgaraxe.net/

```html
<div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" >
   <div class = "container">
   <!--Navigation -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand">Edgar Axelsson</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
  </div>
   <div>
   <div class "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
   <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Comment: line no. 36 you are missing **=** for declaring class

Comment: @AshokShah Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using id on your data-target. Try

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#testnavbar" aria-expanded="true">
```

on your button and

```
<div class="collapse in" "collapse="" navbar-collapse="" navheadercollapse"="" id="testnavbar" aria-expanded="true">
```

on your div.

Also, note that your div does not have an = on your class - that seems to be a typo, so the div line should look like:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="testnavbar">
```